# Update multiple rows in Mysql DB

Tags: sql-update

I have a form which I am trying to use to update stock levels in a mysql DB.

On the form I  have a jquery plugin `relcopy.js`, which I use  to increase the amount of form rows as required. I have appended the text box inputs with the [] square brackets to have them picked up as an array when posted, i.e `lst_Product[]` and so on.

The form page posts to an insert page which contains the following code. It is intended to select the required products who's stock levels I wish to update and insert the new values.

If I post one line from the input form to be updated, the code works fine. If I post let's say three lines from the input form it will update only the third entry.

I suspect I am going wrong here in a "foreach or while" scenario, but I am stumped as to how to resolve it. I would appreciate it if one of you could point me in the right direction. nI would prefer to continue using the mysqli extension approach.

```
<?php session_start();?>

<?php require_once('../Connections/connpay.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('../functions/global_functions.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('../functions/account_functions.php'); ?> 
<?php
foreach ($_POST['lst_product']as $row=>$product_id);

//$product_id = clean_data($_POST['lst_product']);
$quantity = clean_data($_POST['txt_quantity'][$row]);
$company_id = clean_data($_POST['hidden_company_id']);
 ?>
 <?php 
 //Lets connect to the database
 if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
     exit("Failed to connect to the database".mysqli_connect_error());}
 ?>
 <?php 
    $query = "SELECT product_id,stock_level,item_cost FROM acc_stock_items WHERE company_id = '$company_id' AND product_id = '$product_id'";
 $result = $conn->query($query);
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
 if (!empty($row['product_id'])){
     $current_stock = $row['stock_level'];
      $update_quantity = ($current_stock + $quantity);

        $query = "UPDATE acc_stock_items SET stock_level = '$update_quantity' WHERE product_id = '$product_id'";


 if ($conn->query($query)===TRUE){
    //Header("Location:../view_stock_items.php");
echo"all good";}
  else {
      echo "Error:".$conn->error;
  }
   }
$conn->close();
 ?>
 <?php print_r($query)?>
 Selected list item is :<?php echo $product_id;?><br>
The company id is: <?php echo $company_id;?>
```

That's my issue

Comment: you do realize you can do "math" in an update query? `update ... SET stock_level = stock_level + $quantity`? your version is subject to race conditions, and can "lose" inventory.

Comment: Thank's for that Marc, I will have a read up on the term "race conditions" as I do not want to loose inventory if at all possible. That said, are you able to point out where I am going wrong in my code?

Comment: you roundtrip the current in-stock value through your code. it is possible that some OTHER parallel script could be doing the same thing at the same time. both read the same number (say, 50 items), both do the same math on it, but one does 50+10 and the other does 50-5. whichever update executes LAST will win, and you end up with 60 or 45 as stock, not 50+10-5 = 55

Comment: The issue is that it is updating only one row, no problem with calculations.